# Rotate or exchange x-y axis in geopandas dataframe plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapefile, geopandas

I'm new to geopandas dataframes and I got a GeoDataframe which coordinates make a plot very large. I intend to rotate the plot 90° or change the x-y coordinates from each of the polygons. I haven't achieved any of these options.

I also want to put a legend of other GeoDataframe (this one with Points), but i'm afraid that with the rotation, the legend will also be rotated (if.. it's possible).

Until now, the code looks like this:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import data
Zones = gpd.read_file('myfile_with_polygons.shp')
Barr = pd.read_csv('myfile_with_LongLat_Coordinates.csv')

# Create GeoDataFrame from Pandas Dataframe
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(Barr.Longitud, Barr.Latitud)]
Barr = gpd.GeoDataFrame(Barr, crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}, geometry=geometry)

# plots
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_title('such title')
Zones.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='lightgray', edgecolor='gray')
Barr.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='green', edgecolor='gray')
plt.axis('scaled')

plt.show()
```

**Edit:**
Format of `myfile_with_LongLat_Coordinates.csv` file:

```
Name,Longitud,Latitud
My Name,-72.5,-30.7
Such Wow,-69.47,-21.93
Very Name,-71.92,-18.53
...
```

Where the GeoDataFrame `Zones` has a format:

```
    Zone_name    geometry
0       ZoneA    (POLYGON ((-541621.6191 1675026.112, -541621.1...
1       ZoneB    POLYGON ((636925.4216666555 6552020.6959, 3679...
2       ZoneC    (POLYGON ((226598.6520999998 3110548.9596, 276...
....
```

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)